# Atom find and replace: How to search recursively under a given directory, into files matching a filename pattern?

Tags: replace, directory, find, filenames, atom-editor

I want to search all package.json files containing a given word under a "node_modules" directory.

[image: This does not yield any result]

**node_modules/**/package.json** returns no result (and does not even seem to search anything, returning almost instantly).

Using any of the below values yield plenty of result, including several from files named 'package.json'

- node_modules
- node_modules/**/*
- node_modules/**

**Just in case:**

Ubuntu 16.04

Atom 1.10.2

Find-and-replace package 0.201.0

---

**Is there a syntax that would work ?**

Comment: You should check the "Exclude VCS ignored path" option in the core settings panel.

Comment: It looks obvious when one knows it, but I did not.
It works, many thanks @Fab313 :-)